# Use same headers for every request

Tags: http, go

I want to be able to use the same headers for every request made by an HTTP client without having to specify them for every request like so:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprintf("https://%s", endpoint), nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error making request to endpoint: %+v", err)
    return p, err
}
req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer")
req.Header.Add("Version", "2017-11-23") 
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

Is there a way to configure this on the client?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a function to encapsulate the code to create and configure the request:

```
func newRequest(endpoint string) (*http.Request, error) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprintf("https://%s", endpoint), nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer")
    req.Header.Add("Version", "2017-11-23") 
    return req, nil
}
```

A more complicated approach is to implement a [round tripper](https://godoc.org/net/http#RoundTripper) that adds the headers and delegates to another round tripper:

```
type transport struct {
    underlyingTransport http.RoundTripper
}

func (t *transport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer")
    req.Header.Add("Version", "2017-11-23") 
    return t.underlyingTransport.RoundTrip(req)
}
```

Use it to create a [client](https://godoc.org/net/http#Client) like this:

```
c := http.Client{Transport: &transport{ underlyingTransport: http.DefaultTransport } }
```

The transport adds the headers on calls to `c.Do()`, `c.Get()`, `c.Post()`, etc.

Comment: thank you for the extra detail on working with the `RoundTripper` type